# Как сохранить реферальную ссылку?

Tags: php

Хочу организовать реферальную систему на сайте. Встал вопрос. К примеру есть ссылка mydomain.ru/reg?ref=12345 с параметром реферала, человек при переходе по ней будет попадать на страницу для регистрации. Куда лучше сохранить id реферала, чтобы если человек пришедший на сайт по это ссылке перед регистрацией погулял по страницам сайта эта ссылка не затерлась? Правильно ли будет хранить эти данные в сессии?

Comment: Запишите в куки или сессию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше в cookie записать. Это не такая важная информация, да и пользователь незнающий не заметит разницы. А знающий и без того сможет этот id снести.